# Element centered with translate(-50%, -50%) - transition not working

Tags: css

I have a div:

```
<div class="element">
</div>
```

which is centered on screen using these css properties:

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Now I want this div to change its height after adding a class

```
.bigger {
    height: 80%;
}
```

but I want it to animate, so I added a transition property:

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

however height isn't animated after adding 'bigger' class. How to get it working?
Note that I actually use SASS and Jeet grid system to center this div (using @include align(b)).
Here is working CodePen - [codepen](http://codepen.io/mbrnwsk/pen/zGxOyN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
transition: height .4s ease-in-out, transform .4s ease in-out;
```

change to:

```
transition: height .4s ease-in-out, transform .4s ease-in-out;
```

the transition-timing-function is `ease-in-out` not `ease in-out`